Ajax request works succesfully in local but not working in web server. I use Django, Docker. I loads long time and after
Ajax request works successfully locally but not on the web server. I'm using Django and Docker. I've checked all my settings in my docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile, settings.py, urls.py, etc. After loading for a long time, the console shows a message saying "no response." Here's my Ajax view:
    function ShowOTP () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/createcustomer/',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'first_name': $('#first_name').val(), 'last_name': $('#last_name').val(), 'number_prefix': $('#number_prefix').val(), 'phone_number': $('#phone_number').val(), 'otp_form': 'otp_form'
            },

            success: (response) => {

                if (response["valid"] == 'True') {
                    document.getElementById('otpshow').click(); 
                    countdownOTP("#countdown", 2, 0);
                }
                if (response["valid"] == 'False') {
                    window.location = ''
                }

            },
            error: (error) => {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    };


Can you share error log in browser
and also the view function
